# why is output won't continue to next part of program

Tags: c++

When I run this code on ide separately I can make it work, although when I add it together it won't continue to the next part of the program. it allows user input then won't go to the display menu. does it have to do with the two void displayTime?

please if you can fix the code to make it run, submit code that I can use to fix it. I am new at C++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int hour12, min12, sec12;
    string ampm;

    cout << "Please enter the initial time in 12-hour format (HH:MM:SS AM/PM): ";
    cin >> hour12 >> min12 >> sec12 >> ampm;

    cout << "The initial time is: " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour12 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << min12 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << sec12 << " " << ampm << endl;

}
void displayMenu( ) {

    cout << "**************************\n"
         << "*\t\t\t\t*\n"
         << "*\t1-Add One Hour\t\t*\n"
         << "*\t2-Add One Minute\t*\n"
         << "*\t3-Add One Second\t*\n"
         << "*\t4-Exit Program\t\t*\n"
         << "**************************\n";
}

void displayTime(int &hour12, int &min12, int &sec12, string &ampm, int &hour24,
                  int &min24, int &sec24) {

    cout << "**************************\n"
         << "*\t\t\t\t*\n"
         << "*\t12-Hour Clock\t\t*\n"
         << "*\t" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour12 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << min12 << ":"
         << setw(2) << setfill('0') << sec12 << " " << ampm << "\t*\n"
         << "*\t24-Hour Clock\t\t*\n"
         << "*\t" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour24 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << min24 << ":"
         << setw(2) << setfill('0') << sec24 << "\t*\n"
         << "**************************\n";
}

void addOneHour (int &hour ) {

    hour++;
}

void addOneMin(int &min) {

    min++;
}

void addOneSec (int &sec) {

    sec++;
}

void displayTime() {
    int hour12 = 12, min12 = 0, sec12 = 0, hour24 = 0, min24 = 0, sec24 = 0;
    string ampm = "AM";

    

    displayTime(hour12, min12, sec12, ampm, hour24, min24, sec24);
    displayMenu();

    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    while (choice != 4) {

        switch (choice) {

            case 1:
                addOneHour(hour12);
                hour24++;
                break;

            case 2:
                addOneMin(min12);
                min24++;
                break;

            case 3:
                addOneSec(sec12);
                sec24++;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Invalid choice. Please try again.\n";
        }

        if (hour12 == 12 && min12 == 0 && sec12 == 0 && ampm == "AM") {

            ampm = "PM";
        }
        else if (hour12 == 12 && min12 == 0 && sec12 == 0 && ampm == "PM") {

            ampm = "AM";
        }
        else if (hour12 > 12) {

            hour12 -= 12;
            ampm = "PM";
        }

        if (min24 == 60) {

            min24 = 0;
            hour24++;
        }

        if (sec24 == 60) {

            sec24 = 0;
            min24++;
        }

        if (hour24 == 24) {

            hour24 = 0;
        }

        displayTime(hour12, min12, sec12, ampm, hour24, min24, sec24);
        displayMenu();

        cin >> choice;
    }

    cout << "Goodbye!\n";

}
```

This is the flowchart im trying to follow in C++

START Program

Get User Input for the Initial Time

LOOP

Display Menu (Process)

IF Add Hour? (Decision)

```
Add Hour (Process)
```

Display Time (Process)

IF Add Minute? (Decision)

```
Add Minute (Process)
```

Display Time (Process)

IF Add Second? (Decision)

```
Add Second (Process)
```

Display Time (Process)

IF EXIT? (Decision)

```
Exit (Process)
```

END LOOP

Comment: The execution of the program starts with the `main` function. If you want it to go to `input`, you have to call it from there.

Comment: Also, when you call `input()`, it will not modify the variables in `main`, it has it's own, completely separate `hour12`, `min12` and `sec12`. And furthermore, it will not accept input in the form `HH:MM:SS`, only `HH MM SS`.

Comment: I edited and started with the int main, now it'll allow input but won't continue to the next part of displaying the menu!!!

Comment: I think you need to read some more about what functions are and how to use them in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: Yes, a function with a `void` return type can't return any value. This is all covered in the introduction to functions in any decent book.

Comment: can anyone post the code to make this work? I'm confused

Comment: @jimmyCX You don't fully understand how functions work, but you have written code with about 20 functions. That's never going to work. Instead write the code slowly, you don't have to write all the code at once. Just write some code with two functions, that solves a tiny part of the whole problem. Then when you have that working add one more function. Then when you have that working add another function. And so on until you have solved the whole problem. This is how all programmers work, even the experts, no-one writes all the code all at once.

Comment: To get you started, the flowchart is the structure of `main`. Don't call any functions except inside `main`. (You seem to be treating functions as a form of `goto`, which is a mistake.)

Comment: Start off by putting `displayMenu( );` on the next line after `cout << "The initial time is: " << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hour12 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << min12 << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << sec12 << " " << ampm << endl;`